# Invalid number error

Tags: oracle

Hi I'm doing a dimensional modeling exercise in college and I'm trying to convert the `total_price` entry in two of the database tables to euro so they will be in the dimensional table as euro. The two tables are `tournament1` and `tournament2` and the dimensional table is `dim_tournament`. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
insert into Dim_tournament (Tournament_SK, total_price, Tournament_DESC)
Select 
  seq_Tournament.nextVal, 
  total_price, 
  t_descriprion  
From (
       select 
         t_id, 
         cast(to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00')as integer), 
         t_descriprion 
       from Tournament1
       union all
       select 
         t_id, 
         cast(to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00')as integer), 
         t_descriprion from Tournament2
     );
```

This is the error I keep getting when running this:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but it looks like you're converting/formatting `total_price` to a currency string ("$5.99"). If that is true then the currency symbol is probably your problem.

Comment: Is this query running finr? `Select 
  seq_Tournament.nextVal, 
  total_price, 
  t_descriprion  
From (
       select 
         t_id, 
         cast(to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00')as integer), 
         t_descriprion 
       from Tournament1
       union all
       select 
         t_id, 
         cast(to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00')as integer), 
         t_descriprion from Tournament2
     );`

Answer (score 1):

This:

> `cast(to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00')as integer),`

is wrong.

Assuming total_price is defined as `number` the result of converting e.g. 1234.56 will be:

```
EUR1,234.56
```

(the exact output depends on your NLS settings).

Now the *string* `EUR1,234.56` is **not** a valid number any more (at least not to a computer). So your cast to an integer fails.

If you only want to display the total price as a formatted string, only `to_char()` is required. Remove the `cast()`